# Parse: Update user location upon app open from background/inactive state (Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a location-based social networking iPhone app written in Swift and using the Parse SDK.

When the app launches, if the user is logged in, the PFQueryTableViewController is loaded. This is the home page that basically shows a live feed of posts by users within a x-mile radius where users can like or comment on those posts.

Currently, when the user moves to a new location (outside the set mile radius) then goes back into the app, the same feed shows, even if the user pulls-to-refresh the tableview. The new feed of posts only updates to the new location when the user quits the app and launches the app again.

My goal is to have the user's current location update after the user exits (not quits) the app by pressing the iPhone home button or multi-tasking to another app, then opens (not relaunches) the app again. In other words, the feed should update to the new location when the app becomes active again. I think I may have to somehow call some of the functions in the PFQueryTableViewController from `applicationDidBecomeActive` but I am not sure.

I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

In my PFQueryTableViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    queryForLocation()
    queryForLikes()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.loadObjects()

}

func queryForLocation() {

    /* From documentation:
    When the following code is run, the following happens:

    1) An internal CLLocationManager starts listening for location updates (via startsUpdatingLocation).
    2) Once a location is received, the location manager stops listening for location updates (via stopsUpdatingLocation) and a PFGeoPoint is created from the new location. If the location manager errors out, it still stops listening for updates, and returns an NSError instead.
    3) Your block is called with the PFGeoPoint

    ***Are we supposed to use `startsUpdatingLocation` somewhere? (So that it updates the location (currLocation) because it is used in queryForTable() to return the query***

    */

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // store the new geoPoint in currLocation GeoPoint property
            self.currLocation = geoPoint

            // this should call queryForTable
            self.loadObjects()

        } else {
            // Unable to fetch the current device's location.
        }

    }

}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")

    // self.currLocation obtained from `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` call in queryForLocation() but does not seem to be update to new location on app open (not launch).
    if let userLocation = self.currLocation {

        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: userLocation, withinMiles: 5)

        query.includeKey("User")

        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.NetworkOnly

        // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table and then subsequently do a query against the network.
        if (self.objects?.count == 0) {

            query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork

        }

        query.limit = 200;

        return query

    } else {

        /* How the application should react if there is no location available */

        return PFQuery()

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your `queryForLocation()` only in your `viewDidLoad` method but when the app goes background then foreground, `viewDidLoad` is not recalled, that's why you don't have a new position.

You might just register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification, so you will be notified when the app is brought back to the foreground.

Just add (if you are not using Xcode 7.3, you may have to use `selector: "willEnterForeground"`) to your `viewDidLoad` method :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.comeFromBackground), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)



func comeFromBackground() {
   // This is where you should do your request for location again
}
```

So everytime your app goes background->foreground this function will be called.

Don't forget to remove the observer in the `viewDidDisappear` :

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer! Question: Will `comeFromBackground()` still get called if the user entered the background from a different view controller (besides the PFQueryTableViewController)? Also, would it be better to notify the PFQueryTableViewController to update location from the AppDelegate instead of inside the PFQueryTableViewController? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: If you want another controller to be notified if the app goes background you can simply add the same observer just change the selector if you want to call another function. I don't really understand your second question though.

Comment: So the code you provided will or will not call comeFromBackground() if the user was on another viewcontroller (i.e.: the comments page of a post) as they entered the background?

Comment: If you didn't add the observer on others controllers and if you called the `removeObserver` in the `viewDidDisappear` the `comeFromBackground()` function should not be called.

Comment: Thanks. I've been testing this approach and noticed that it doesn't always work (the feed doesn't always update to the new location). I think that queryForTable() may have to be called again by calling loadObjects()...When the app first launches, it always works correctly. So, my thinking is that I have to replicate whatever happens (i.e. whichever methods get called) on startup inside the `comeFromBackground` method. What do you think?